# Make request data available from different places

Tags: node.js, express, apollo-server

We are building a middleware with apollo-server, express, and nodejs.

There is some info in the HTTP request headers that we’ll like to be available from different places down the call stack without the need to be passing them as parameters or touching each resolver, some kind of java thread-local.

We have a solution using async_hooks, but in some cases, it doesn’t work, we tried AsyncLocalStorage with no success, so we are looking for alternatives.

Apollo → Express Middleware → Apollo Context -> Resolvers → Other Code ...→ A REST call needing the header in original HTTP request

We have a working solution with the context, we were looking for a more global solution using middleware

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your needs, could you please show some code example ?

Comment: It's a little complex the demo, but is just make http info that come in the request to be available latter for logging, forward some headers to other servers, later down the call stack, some kind of per-request duration storage, thanks.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/ and then just return the headers/datas you want in context instead of users ?

Comment: We have a working solution with the context, we were looking for a more global solution using middleware, thanks.

Comment: i don't really know appolo server, but as you're using express you have a direct access to the request object normally app.use(function(req, res, next){ ....})

Comment: This a diagram explaining the need: Apollo → Express Middleware →Apollo Context -> Resolvers → Other Code ...→ A REST call needing the header in original HTTP request.

Comment: ho ok, i'm starting to understand your flow, as i can see you have the good approach by using the context, maybe others good people will have another solution for you :) I complete your question with infos you gave in comment to make it clearer

Comment: Were you able to work it out? The async hooks seem to lose context when I tried a similar approach. Tried also to set the async context via an Apollo plugin with no success

Comment: Eyal, yes It worked fine with async_hooks.